How to use stored procedure parameters as dynamic content in copy activity using ADF
I have designed a copy activity pipeline in ADF and called a stored procedure which takes two parameters as input.
I want to use the parameters as dynamic content in copy activity when stored procedure calls.
Main pipeline is 
inside for each activity I used web activity and if statement
inside for each activity
I activated the 2nd if else condition and inside it there is copy activity Copy activity
in copy activity, there is a stored procedure calling Stored procedure
for test purposes, I just hardcode the values in add dynamic content that the stored procedure will take
@json('{ "Calendars": { "value": "FY25,FY26", "type": "String" }, "PPiviotLevel": { "value": 0, "type": "Int32" } }')
Values in dynamic content 
Now my aim is to use this JSON in a database table and web activity which I used already to call the column name and pass these two values in the Stored procedure.
The column name in the database is SP_PARAMETERS, But I am unable how to save these values in the SP_PARAMETERS column so that I can call and use this when Stored Procedure calls.

can you add output of your web activity and what you are passing as if condition?

I just want to save parameters in JSON in db and get from dynamic content in copy activity when stored procedure called

can you add output of your web activity? and what you are passing in if condition?

'{ "Calendars": { "value": "FY25,FY26", "type": "String" }, "PPiviotLevel": { "value": 0, "type": "Int32" } }' from where you are getting this json?

can you please explain step by step what you are doing in whole pipeline?

First from lookup are you getting this json values which you are passing it further to web activity and copy activity?


The column name in the database is SP_PARAMETERS, But I am unable how to save these values in the SP_PARAMETERS column so that I can call and use this when Stored Procedure calls.

To save that value in SP_PARAMETERS column you need to use the Additional column property in copy activity in that value should be pass in the string format only so you can use string function.

In sink add the table where you want to store the data and in mapping map the column correctly.

Output:

Now, you can use lookup activity to call them again and use it as stored procedure parameter in it.

Yes this is the actual requirement, Thank you for your support and time.
